# On folding should not see blank line - Sublime Text IDE

Tags: javascript, html, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using sublime and on folding a function, I am seeing a gap in the folded function with a blank line. I dont want the last line to be removed from function, but on folding no gap should be seen in image 2 between folded lines.

[image]

[image]

> **Note:** On removing line 114, the gap in folded snippet is removed. But I want a blank line before the code ends in function.

I am open to any javascript-plugin or trick to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is by addind a `//` (comment) in the last line... But I think that's ok :)

Comment: I dont want to add scrap in all the bunch of code, just to achieve this. ;(

Comment: And that still means no gap at the last, which I want. Else, it will consider that commented line as text, and my aim is defeated lastly.

Comment: Well, you could use something like `//remove later`, and when you are ready and don't need the folding any longer, you can remove them all easily.